# Converting pandas dataframe to string with emojis

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to convert pandas dataframe to string, but I can't justify it correctly and save utf-8 values

I'm using `pandas.DataFrame.to_string` function with different params (code below) but not able to achieve a desired look: table justified by left and showing utf-8 values normally.

```py
data = [['Fire', 'das Feuer', b'\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5'],
        ['Air', 'der Wind', b'\xF0\x9F\x8D\x83'],
        ['Water', 'Wasser', b'\xF0\x9F\x8C\x8A']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['English', 'German', 'Pic'])

string = df.to_string(columns=['German', 'Pic'], index=False, header=False, justify='left')
```

How it looks:

```
              das Feuer b'\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5'
               der Wind b'\xF0\x9F\x8D\x83'
               Wasser b'\xF0\x9F\x8C\x8A'
```

How I want it to look:

```
das Feuer 
der Wind 
Wasser
```

I'm out of ideas. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### `decode`

```
df = df.assign(Pic=df.Pic.str.decode('utf-8'))

s = '\n'.join(map(' '.join, zip(df.German, df.Pic)))
print(s)

das Feuer 
der Wind 
Wasser
```

Comment: Why use `assign`? `df['Pic'] = df['Pic'].str.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: I make using `assign` a habit.  I dislike augmenting parts of the dataframe and I try to avoid it.  It makes it easier for me to keep track what I'm doing.  Personal preference, but it has proven useful.  It also fits the functional paradigm of no side effects.  And I'm partial to that.

Comment: @Dan Can I put that in a variable instead of printing it right away?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your dataframe to utf-8 before defining `str`.

```py
df.Pic = df.Pic.str.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: `df['Pic'].str.decode('utf-8')`. No need for `apply`

Answer (score 0):

loop over the index , and print the column "German" and column "Pic" . and decode column Pic" in "utf-8"

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['Fire', 'das Feuer', b'\xF0\x9F\x94\xA5'],
        ['Air', 'der Wind', b'\xF0\x9F\x8D\x83'],
        ['Water', 'Wasser', b'\xF0\x9F\x8C\x8A']]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['English', 'German', 'Pic'])
for i in df.index:
    print(df['German'][i],df['Pic'][i].decode("utf-8"))


das Feuer 
der Wind 
Wasser
```

[image]